# How to post a sidecar arousel post on instagram using python

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

I am having trouble finding a python library to post carousels posts/ multiside posts on Instagram through python. Currently I'm using instabot library. Is there a better option?

````
from instabot import Bot

def post(username, password , img , discription):

    bot = Bot()
    bot.login(username = username, password = password)
    bot.upload_photo(img, caption = discription)```
````